# Is it actually possible to mux subtitles into a .mkv file using GStreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

Wish in the document of matroskamux there could be an example demonstrating how to mux subtitles. After a couple of days trying, I doubt it is doable. Maybe it is a bug that matroskamux can not mux subtitles, except when the text stream is in subtitle/x-kate format. Below is the pipeline description that failed. Can someone please tell me where it went wrong, or verify that it is indeed a bug. Thanks.

```
gst-launch-1.0                \
videotestsrc num-buffers=300  \
! videoconvert                \
! theoraenc                   \
! MUXER.video_%u              \
filesrc location=src.srt      \
! subparse                    \
! text/x-raw,format=utf8      \
! MUXER.subtitle_0            \
matroskamux name=MUXER        \
! filesink location=dst.mkv
```

Below is a .srt file that can be used to try the above `gst-launch-1.0` command.

```
1
00:00:01,000 --> 00:00:02,000
one

2
00:00:02,000 --> 00:00:03,000
two

3
00:00:03,000 --> 00:00:04,000
three

4
00:00:04,000 --> 00:00:05,000
four

5
00:00:05,000 --> 00:00:06,000
five

6
00:00:06,000 --> 00:00:07,000
six

7
00:00:07,000 --> 00:00:08,000
seven

8
00:00:08,000 --> 00:00:09,000
eight

9
00:00:09,000 --> 00:00:10,000
nine

10
00:00:10,000 --> 00:00:11,000
ten
```

Comment: Well for starters.. `mp4mux` will not create MKV files but MP4 files. Regardless on how you name them at the filesink.

Comment: @Florian Zwoch Copy&paste a wrong pipeline description. That was dumb. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: So how does it fail? With an error? Or is the subtitle not displayed?

Comment: @FlorianZwoch Just updated the question. If you have GStreamer installed, you can try it and see the error messages. I doubt it's doable. Maybe it's a bug. If you succeed, please let me know your pipeline description. Thanks. By the way, environment variable `GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR` might be helpful.

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra No, last time I tried GStreamer was about 4 or 5 months ago. After that, new version came out but I don't have time to check if it works now yet. If you can solve this, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Cody. I tried last week, and same behaviour

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra Thanks for confirming.

Comment: I have similiar pipeline, and I think its a matter of subparse producing /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSubParse:subparse0.GstPad:src: caps = text/x-raw, format=(string)pango-markup even though its asked for utf8. Don't have solution for that :(
My question for similiar thing is linked below, read comments under Florian answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59361367/gstreamer-fakesink0sink-4096-bytes-dts-none-pts-none-duration-none-fo/59372515#59372515