# GStreamer - fakesink0:sink) (4096 bytes, dts: none, pts: none, duration: none for first text lines read by filesrc from srt file

Tags: gstreamer

Why in following pipeline I have None timestamp at beginning of reading text from .srt file with subtitles?

Its a problem for me as I want to mux it later with h264 video from other src, and that fails due to "Buffer has no PTS" from muxer.

GStreamer version 1.14.5

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc do-timestamp=true location=English.srt  ! queue ! fakesink silent=false -v
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFakeSink:fakesink0: last-message = event   ******* (fakesink0:sink) E (type: stream-start (10254), GstEventStreamStart, stream-id=(string)a02d40ac74fcf80941cc61947d76a1e054212aa98d213ab8cf403f1634f3abb0, flags=(GstStreamFlags)GST_STREAM_FLAG_NONE, group-id=(uint)1;) 0x563e90b389e0
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFakeSink:fakesink0: last-message = event   ******* (fakesink0:sink) E (type: segment (17934), GstEventSegment, segment=(GstSegment)"GstSegment, flags=(GstSegmentFlags)GST_SEGMENT_FLAG_NONE, rate=(double)1, applied-rate=(double)1, format=(GstFormat)GST_FORMAT_TIME, base=(guint64)0, offset=(guint64)0, start=(guint64)0, stop=(guint64)18446744073709551615, time=(guint64)0, position=(guint64)0, duration=(guint64)18446744073709551615;";) 0x563e90b38a50
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFakeSink:fakesink0: last-message = preroll   ******* 
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFakeSink:fakesink0: last-message = chain   ******* (fakesink0:sink) (4096 bytes, dts: none, pts: none, duration: none, offset: -1, offset_end: 4095, flags: 00000040 discont , meta: none) 0x7f35f0008060
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFakeSink:fakesink0: last-message = chain   ******* (fakesink0:sink) (4096 bytes, dts: none, pts: none, duration: none, offset: -1, offset_end: 4095, flags: 00000000 , meta: none) 0x7f35f0008170
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFakeSink:fakesink0: last-message = chain   ******* (fakesink0:sink) (4096 bytes, dts: none, pts: none, duration: none, offset: -1, offset_end: 4095, flags: 00000000 , meta: none) 0x7f35f0008280
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFakeSink:fakesink0: last-message = chain   ******* (fakesink0:sink) (4096 bytes, dts: none, pts: none, duration: none, offset: -1, offset_end: 4095, flags: 00000000 , meta: none) 0x7f35f0008390
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFakeSink:fakesink0: last-message = chain   ******* (fakesink0:sink) (4096 bytes, dts: 0:00:00.001037500, pts: 0:00:00.001037500, duration: none, offset: -1, offset_end: 4095, flags: 00000000 , meta: none) 0x7f35f00084a0
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFakeSink:fakesink0: last-message = chain   ******* (fakesink0:sink) (4096 bytes, dts: 0:00:00.001103400, pts: 0:00:00.001103400, duration: none, offset: -1, offset_end: 4095, flags: 00000000 , meta: none) 0x7f35f00085b0
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFakeSink:fakesink0: last-message = chain   ******* (fakesink0:sink) (4096 bytes, dts: 0:00:00.001135300, pts: 0:00:00.001135300, duration: none, offset: -1, offset_end: 4095, flags: 00000000 , meta: none) 0x7f35f00086c0
```

Part of file to read:

```
1
00:00:00,900 --> 00:00:37,690
Flesh and sin die.

2
00:00:42,530 --> 00:00:46,410
Die with Christ, that's it.
Rise with Christ.

3
00:00:46,620 --> 00:00:50,660
That's it. Holy Spirit, come.
Holy Spirit come, set her free.

4
00:00:51,120 --> 00:00:53,080
Die with Christ.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have absolute no logic in your pipeline. Other than the file has the extension `.srt` no one knows with what kind of data we deal with here. You probably want something like `subparse`.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc do-timestamp=true location=English.srt  ! subparse ! queue ! fakesink silent=false -v
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 
Yes and no :)

Thanks to subparse I was able to get proper PTS when subtitle file was parsed. 

But still I'm not sure why in original pipeline there was PTS as None? In what circumstances that may happen?

My current pipeline is:
```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc do-timestamp=true location=English.srt  ! application/x-subtitle ! subparse subtitle-encoding=utf8 !  text/x-raw,format=\(string\)utf8 ! fakesink silent=false -vmt
```


which is failing as  for some reason its (string\)pango-markup as output from subparse even though its support format=\(string\)utf8

Comment: So subparse should use "format=(string)utf8" capability when linking to fakesink. But its not.

Comment: If you don't have a parser you only have filesrc and fakesink. What do you expect to happen in this case? GStreamer doesn't know what to do, so how does it know about any pts?

Comment: Also, subparse is a parser not a converter. Since SubRip includes markup subparse will give you a markup format. If you want the raw strings or whatever you want you need to pull it out of the markup format.

Comment: In terms of my expectation about PTS from filesrc, in 5th line of output in question:
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFakeSink:fakesink0: last-message = chain   ******* (fakesink0:sink) (4096 bytes, dts: 0:00:00.001037500, pts: 0:00:00.001037500, duration: none, offset: -1, offset_end: 4095, flags: 00000000 , meta: none) 0x7f35f00084a0

Pts is set, so its not consistent, as at the beginning its none and than is set - I'm confused here. 
Other thing is those PTS  seems to contain time of reading  every line which isn't too useful for synchronisation downstream.

Comment: In terms of my expectation to subparse return raw string I've find it in gst-inspect output:
SRC template: 'src'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      text/x-raw
                 format: { (string)pango-markup, (string)utf8 }

so seems that I may request (string)utf8 on output. But apparently I cannot do that in this pipeline, as always is pango-markup.

In terms of converting pango-markup to raw strings, do you know any GStreamer plugin which may do that for me?

Comment: Not really. `pango_parse_markup()` from the pango library is a helper for that I guess. The caps from the element are possible outputs. It does not mean all formats are available for a particular stream. Similar to a video decoder may offer multiple formats, but the streams dictates what actually is being decoded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204447/discussion-between-lukasz-gawron-and-florian-zwoch).